# Problem with write in subcollections Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore database and has the following structure:

```
collection (teachers): {
  doc (id): {
    name: name
    lastName: lastName
    collection (classes): {
      doc (id): {
        name: math
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the headmaster is able to get the `teacher`'s name and add/create some classes for the very same teacher. The problem comes with adding the Firestore rules. I've tried this three rule possibilities, but none worked as expected. I was able to read, but no writing was possible.

1

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /teachers/{teacher} {
        allow get if true;
        allow create if true;
    }
  }
}
```

2

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /teachers/{teacher} {
        allow get if true;
    }
    match /teachers/{teacher}/classes/{class} {
    allow create if true;
  }
}
```

3

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /teachers/{teacher} {
        allow get if true;
      match /classes/{class} {
        allow create if true;
      }
    }
}
```

I'm working with angularfirestore2, by the way.

Comment: How would you identify a user that is a "headmaster"? Are all users "headmasters"? What can do "non-headmasters" users? It is not 100% clear what access rights you want to implement.

Comment: I can identify the headmaster, what I can't do is to set the permission of, once the teacher is set, write in a deeper document based on it's path as I mentioned. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I get from your question is that, you want to give `read, write` for `/teachers/{teacher}/classes/{class}` to some users with `headmaster` role.

For that, first you need to check which users are `headmasters`.

If your teachers doc id is same as userid created in firebase auth, you can add a data field to your teacher document named `isHM` and set this to `true`, if user is headmaster:

```
collection (teachers): {
  doc (id): {
    name: name
    lastName: lastName
    isHM: true
    collection (classes): {
      doc (id): {
        name: math
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now add the following rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /teachers/{teacher}/classes/{class} {

        function isHeadMaster() {
          return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teachers/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isHM;
        }

        // HM can read, write classes
        allow read, write: if isHeadMaster == true;

     }
   }
}
```

or else you need to create a different collection with firebase userid as the doc id and add `isHM` field if the user is headmaster, as follows:

```
collection (headmasters): {
  doc (uid): {
    ----
    isHM: true
    ----
  }
}
```

and then add following rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /teachers/{teacher}/classes/{class} {

        function isHeadMaster() {
          return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/headmasters/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isHM;
        }

        // HM can read, write classes
        allow read, write: if isHeadMaster == true;

     }
   }
}
```

To find more role based access rules, check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access